# We switched from Android Studio to Unity and cant sing app

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, authentication, google-play, sha1

We have app on google play already, which was created in Android studio and now we decided to create new mutation in Unity, but we want to reupload the old app on google play. We have problem with SHA1 key, since Android studio has .jks format and unity needs .keystore. Is there any way we can export it to unity or we need to create new app on google play?

Answer (score 0):

@Yrchdagnir just rename your file it will work in unity as well.